# create another column in kendo grid with de sum of column1 and 2

Tags: asp.net-core, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want the sum of two columns to be added to another column in the kendo grid. Now it is showing that NaN when I use ClientTemplate whereas in the case of ClientGroupColumnTemplate shows the correct result. In my case, I want the result in another column instead of a group column any help?

```
.Columns(c =>
    {  c.Bound(p => p.field1).Title("F1");
       c.Bound(p => p.field2).Title("F2");
       c.Bound(p => p.Total).Title("Total").ClientTemplate("#=calculate(data)#");
})

<script>
    function calculate(data) {
        field1 + p.field2;
        return result;

</script>
```

Comment: You can refer to the [link](https://www.telerik.com/forums/create-another-column-in-grid-with-de-sum-of-column1-and-2).

Comment: Try `function calculate(data) { return data.field1 + data.field2; }`